# Genymotion Displaying Distorted Graphics

Tags: windows-7-x64, genymotion

I've been able to install genymotion on Windows 7 Ultimate.
I've done the below as well...

-Enabled Intel VT tech.  On bios and in Virtualbox. 
- UTC clock enabled.
-Turned up Video Memory to Max.
-Enabled 3D Rendering.
-Genymotion and VirtualBox both upgraded. 
-Added Google Play

Running on intel sandy bridge.
With newer AMD graphics card.

But I'm still getting graphics like this in games.

[image]

Is there anything I can do to fix this?